# Insert to jTable date from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing

hello i am have jTable and i am want insert date from this SQL query to jTable. But i am can"t insert to jTable date from Rank, other date insert correct, but 6 column of jTable is empty.

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_mafia?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8", "root", "qwerty");
    Statement st2 = con.createStatement();

    ResultSet result2 = st2.executeQuery("SELECT t.*, @rank := @Rank + 1 AS rank \n" +
        "FROM (SELECT id_user,(SELECT surname FROM users WHERE id_user=id),(SELECT name FROM users WHERE id_user=id), (SELECT nickname FROM users WHERE id_user=id),SUM(points) AS points FROM RESULT \n" +
        "GROUP BY id_user ORDER BY  points asc) t");

    while (result2.next()) {
        ((DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel()).addRow(new Object[] {
            result2.getString(1), result2.getString(2), result2.getString(3), result2.getString(4), result2.getString(5), result2.getString(6)
        });

    }
    result2.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
}
```

And before query i am want execute this but I do not know where it to insert?:

```
SET @Rank = 0;
```

Comment: Why can't you add the `Rank` type of `Date` into a `JTable`?

Comment: Have you tried using `getDate` instead of `getString`?  The query shouldn't need `\n`

Comment: thank you, question is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Rank var to 0 before SELECT with this: st2.executeUpdate("SET @Rank = 0");

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = (Connection)  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_mafia?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8", "root", "qwerty");
    Statement st2 = con.createStatement();

    st2.executeUpdate("SET @Rank = 0");

    ResultSet result2 = st2.executeQuery("SELECT t.*, @Rank := @Rank + 1 AS rank \n" +
        "FROM (SELECT id_user,(SELECT surname FROM users WHERE id_user=id),(SELECT name FROM users WHERE id_user=id), (SELECT nickname FROM users WHERE id_user=id),SUM(points) AS points FROM RESULT \n" +
        "GROUP BY id_user ORDER BY  points asc) t");

    while (result2.next()) {
        ((DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel()).addRow(new Object[] {
            result2.getString(1), result2.getString(2), result2.getString(3), result2.getString(4), result2.getString(5), result2.getString(6)
        });

    }
    result2.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: And the difference would be?

Comment: setting Rank to 0 before the query, to init the accumulator, I think with:  st2.executeUpdate("SET @Rank = 0");

Comment: Okay, missed that, might want to point that out to the OP as there are enough walls of code on the internet ;)

Comment: Without knowing exactly what the OP wants, won't that always make the `Rank` `1`....?